# Flutter RenderFlex overflowed by 15 pixels on the right inside Column Widget

Tags: flutter

I created a custom ListTile which should have two score centered in the middle and information on the left and right of this ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6daCP.png)).

The information on the left can have arbitrary length and should use TextOverflow.ellipsis when it's too long.
I cannot get this to work since the Text does not seem to know the width it is supposed to have and overflows.
I have tried wrapping the Text widgets into SizedBox, Expanded, etc. This has not worked.

```
    flutter: ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
    flutter: The following message was thrown during layout:
    flutter: A RenderFlex overflowed by 15 pixels on the right.
    flutter:
    flutter: The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal.
    flutter: The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering with a yellow and
    flutter: black striped pattern. This is usually caused by the contents being too big for the RenderFlex.
    flutter: Consider applying a flex factor (e.g. using an Expanded widget) to force the children of the
    flutter: RenderFlex to fit within the available space instead of being sized to their natural size.
    flutter: This is considered an error condition because it indicates that there is content that cannot be
    flutter: seen. If the content is legitimately bigger than the available space, consider clipping it with a
    flutter: ClipRect widget before putting it in the flex, or using a scrollable container rather than a Flex,
    flutter: like a ListView.
    flutter: The specific RenderFlex in question is:
    flutter:   RenderFlex#c64e4 relayoutBoundary=up11 OVERFLOWING
    flutter:   creator: Row ← Expanded ← Row ← Column ← ConstrainedBox ← Container ← Listener ← _GestureSemantics
    flutter:   ← RawGestureDetector ← GestureDetector ← InkWell ← ScopedModelDescendant<BaseballModel> ← ⋯
    flutter:   parentData: offset=Offset(0.0, 0.0); flex=1; fit=FlexFit.tight (can use size)
    flutter:   constraints: BoxConstraints(w=143.0, 0.0<=h<=Infinity)
    flutter:   size: Size(143.0, 70.0)
    flutter:   direction: horizontal
    flutter:   mainAxisAlignment: start
    flutter:   mainAxisSize: max
    flutter:   crossAxisAlignment: center
    flutter:   textDirection: ltr
    flutter:   verticalDirection: down
    flutter: ◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤◢◤
```

My Code is the following:

```
@immutable
class GameTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final Game game;
  Color highligtColor = Colors.red;

  GameTile({this.game});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      child: Container(
        height: 70.0,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 8.0,
                        height: 70.0,
                        color: highligtColor,
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              game.awayTeam.name,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              game.homeTeam.name,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        game.awayRuns,
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        game.homeRuns,
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(game.getFormattedDate()),
                            Text(game.getFormattedTime()),
                          ]),
                      Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 10.0),
                        child: Container(),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 52):

Just wrap the overflowed widget with `Flexible`

```
new Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            new Checkbox(
              onChanged: (bool){},
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: new Text(
                "This text can be so loooooooooooooong",
              ),
            ),

          ],
        ),
```

Comment: Exactly the case... Thanks 

Answer (score 14):

#### Explanation of `Flexible` or `Expanded` Solution

Inside a `Row`, a `Text` widget will never line-wrap nor show ellipses when not inside an `Expanded` or `Flexible` widget (or another widget which constrains width).

When Flutter performs layout for `Row` or `Column`, any non-flex factor widgets get laid out in **unbounded space**.  i.e. without any constraints. (`Flexible`, `Expanded` and `Spacer` are the only flex-factor widgets.)

So when `Text` is being laid out inside the `Row`, it will never be so wide as to hit a width constraint and get wrapped because...

... there are ***no constraints*** during `Row` layout for ***non-flex*** factor widgets.

---

Placing the `Text` widget inside a `Flexible` or `Expanded` will cause Flutter to **calculate remaining space** during `Row` layout and impose that constraint.  This will cause wrapping if needed & ellipses if specified: `Text("blahblah", overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis)`.

[More details in a related RenderFlex overflowed question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66736127/2301224).

#### Example Code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class FlexTextWrapPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flex Text Wrap'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                MySpacer(width: 100),
                Text("This should easily wrap, but doesn't because I'm in INFINITE SPACE"),
                MySpacer(width: 100),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                MySpacer(width: 100),
                Expanded(child: Text("This should easily wrap, and DOES because I'm in BOUNDED SPACE")),
                MySpacer(width: 100),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(
            width: 400,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                MySpacer(width: 100),
                Expanded(
                    child: Text("This should easily wrap, and DOES because I'm in BOUNDED SPACE",
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, // default is .clip
                      maxLines: 2,),// default is 1
                ),
                MySpacer(width: 100),
              ],
            ),
          ),

        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MySpacer extends StatelessWidget {
  final double width;

  MySpacer({this.width});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(child: SizedBox(width: width, height: 16,), color: Colors.lightBlueAccent,);
  }
}
```

#### Result

[image: Overflow, Wrapping & Ellipses Text]

Answer (score 7):

If you want the child content to just fit the content without being expanded. You must use `Flexible` in combination with `MainAxisSize.min` inside Row:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
    Flexible(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 2),
        child: Text("abc",
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontSize: 13),
          maxLines: 1,
          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down, size: 10, color: Colors.white,)
  ],
)
```

[image: doanbh image]

Answer (score 6):

### About the exception

I ran your code on my phone and an exception occurred only after meddling with the teams names and the width of the widget.

I think this problem arises because your code doesn't adapt to different display sizes well enough, especially if the team names have a different length:

[image: both your widget and the modified version]

### Concrete solution for a more flexible and dynamic widget

I created a modified widget that adapts well to constraint changes and uses the available space in a more clever way. I did this by flattening your nested `Row`s and `Column`s as far as possible, resulting in a more shallow, more flexible widget tree:

```
return InkWell(
  child: Container(
    height: 70.0,
    child: Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(width: 8.0, height: 70.0, color: highlightColor),
        SizedBox(width: 15.0),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(game.awayTeam.name, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
            Text(game.homeTeam.name, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          ],
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Text(game.awayRuns, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
            Text(game.homeRuns, style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
          ],
        ),
        Spacer(),
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(game.getFormattedDate()),
            Text(game.getFormattedTime()),
          ]
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 18.0),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

### General tip when dealing with difficult constraints

Most of the time, it's better to use just a few widgets in a shallow tree. Nesting all kinds of "organizational" widgets, especially `Column`s, `Row`s and `Expanded`s often creates situations where an `Expanded` always requests the same size (or ratio of the parent size) without even considering the dimensions of its content.

That can lead to content overflowing, while there is unused negative space at other parts of the widget.

Comment: Thanks for your thorough explanation and the code suggestion @Marcel, it's much appreciated.
However, there are still some problems with it: Yes, your solution makes better use of whitespace but this leads to visually inconsistent visual list tiles. Check out this screenshot: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/22519290/47095128-e8260580-d22c-11e8-9582-3f16ca57800c.png.
Furthermore, your solution does not satisfy my constraints of placing the scores in the horizontal centre of the list tile. Do you have any idea on how to achieve that?

Comment: Your link doesn't work for me, but I know what you mean: If there are multiple `GameTile`s, the scores have different x positions. This is a difficult design decision, but you could replace the second `Spacer()` with a `SizedBox(width: 16.0)` to always align the scores on the right side... Or you could somehow try to clip the text or even make it scroll, but that would be a whole other problem for itself.

Comment: Recently I developed a marquee widget which can scroll text. If you think that might be a viable option, feel free to check out the pub package: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/marquee

Comment: I'm curious: Did you solve this issue by now? And if so, how?

Answer (score 2):

use `Expanded` or `Flexible` in your parent widget,

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had lottie view as a child of **ROW** and I had put wrong path of lottie asset. and I was getting renderflow error and lottie asset error was not showing at the bottom.
Fixed lottie assets and this got automatically resolved.

Answer (score 0):

**[UPDATE 2023]** Add `Flexible` so that the child element can stretch to fit the remaining space on the screen without causing a width error.

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: CustomHomeServices(
        iconUrl: 'assets/ic_topup.png',
        title: 'Deposit \n',
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pushNamed(
            context,
            '/topup',
            arguments: cardInfo,
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
    // Other children
  ],
),
```